# How to get system images programmatically? (example: disclosure chevron)

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa

I want to create UIImageView with some system-image in it. (Example: the disclosure chevron image, etc.). How can I do so programmatically?

Note: I don't want to download the image and add it to the project, I want to fetch it from the user programmatically / from the Interface Builder.

Comment: Why can't you simply set the button type to (for example) Detail Disclosure? (What are you really attempting to achieve?)

Comment: I want the image itself. I will change the question to be clearer, thanks for letting me realize my question was silly as it was :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From iOS 13 and Xcode 11 you can get system images by giving system name.

```
let image = UIImage(systemName: "info.circle")
```

[image: icons]

Reference : [UIImage Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/3294233-init)

Comment: On Apple Watch I used your solution and put `alarmTimerImage?.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "bell.slash.fill"))` and was able to programatically set the image.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean you can to set the button to use the system disclosure icon, just do as @middaparka suggested and use this:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
```

If you're asking how you can access the image directly, you can't do that. This is your only option: [Use default apple icons for pdfs and docs in iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340083/use-default-apple-icons-for-pdfs-and-docs-in-ios-app)

Comment: This Artwork-Exractor is no good because for iOS-7 you have different system resources (and especially the chevron sign is lighter :) ) so users with different OS's will see different images. That is why I asked for a way that does not involve downloading the images beforehand and planting them as resources inside my project.  If you say that's my only option, I'll be very sad :(

Comment: not exactly, you can access the image in a given state like `[[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight] imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] `

Answer (score 7):

I think [`iOS-Artwork-Extractor`](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor/blob/master/README.md) is the tool you are looking for. It lets you extract the artwork into png files.

There is no clean programmatical way to access the images of system buttons. Quote from the documentation of the UIButton.imageView property:

> The value of the property is `nil` for system buttons.

You may do an off screen rendering of the views and extract the resources on the fly but that's a very shaky approach. It's better to extract every asset you need and use them as intended. You'll suffer much more in the end with the programmatic way.

Comment: This tool is no good because for iOS-7 you have different system resources (and especially the chevron sign is lighter :) ) so users with different OS's will see different images. That is why I asked for a way that does not involve downloading the images beforehand and planting them as resources inside my project.

Comment: You are talking about an OS that hasn't been released yet and you didn't mention iOS7 in the question either.

Comment: Updated the answer but you'll not be much happier with it. :)

Comment: Indeed not happy. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @rmaddy because there doesn't exist a better solution yet. :)

Comment: @allprog That's no reason to accept an answer. No offense to you or your answer :)